# C#: в чем отличие Lazy<T> от аналогичных реализаций?

Tags: c#

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4036851/3129992) показан пример отложенной инициализации свойства класса, выглядит это так:

```
private Lazy<string> _someVariable =new Lazy<string>(SomeClass.IOnlyWantToCallYouOnce);
public string SomeVariable {
    get { return _someVariable.Value; }
}
```

Возник вопрос: чем отличается вышеуказанная инициализация от например такой:

```
private string? _someVariable = null;
public string SomeVariable {
    get {
        if(_someVariable == null) {
            // здесь могу ошибаться, но думаю, что принцип понятен
            _someVariable = new SomeClass().IOnlyWantToCallYouOnce();
        }
        return _someVariable;
    }
}
```

Comment: А ведь еще есть LazyInitializer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. У `Lazy` есть потокобезопасная версия, при реализации же ленивости вручную надо городить DCL и не забыть про `volatile`.
2. Второй вариант использует `null` как маркер отсутствия значения. Если вдруг функция `IOnlyWantToCallYouOnce()` вернет `null` - она будет вызвана еще раз. У `Lazy` же `null` - такое же допустимое значение, как и любое другое, потому что маркер наличия значения хранится отдельно от самого значения.
3. `Lazy` сохраняет не только результат нормального вычисления - но и исключение в случае ошибки, поэтому функция `IOnlyWantToCallYouOnce` будет вызвана только 1 раз чего бы не случилось. Решение же номер два в случае исключения при вызове ничего не сохранит и при повторном обращении попытается получить его еще раз. Иногда это полезно, иногда - вредно.

Comment: было бы замечательно, если бы Вы привели пример потокобезопасной версии.

Comment: @XelaNimed DCL - это double-checked lock, [пример есть даже в википедии :)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Microsoft_.NET_.28Visual_Basic.2C_C.23.29)

Comment: @XelaNimed у `Lazy<T>` три [режима работы](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.lazythreadsafetymode(v=vs.110).aspx). В `None` синхронизация отсутствует, объект не потокобезопасен. В `ExecutionAndPublication` синхронизируются и создание объекта, и публикация (присвоение ссылки) -- это эквивалентно синглтону с двойной проверкой. Во `PublicationOnly` синхронизируется только публикация (значений при этом может создаться несколько). По умолчанию работает `ExecutionAndPublication`.

Comment: @PavelMayorov ссылки "раз" и "два" более не работают...